# Data validation builder from array not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using this code to create a data validation for an array in Google Spreadsheets but I keep getting an error message saying I don't have permission to call cell.setDataValidation ().

```
var array = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveCell();
var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(array,    true).setAllowInvalid(false).build();

cell.setDataValidation(rule);
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of late for the original poster but I just ran into this issue myself and figured I'd post the solution for others. Open up your spreadsheet and navigate to `tools > script manager` you should see your script listed, highlight it and press `run`. It should warn you that you need to give it permission to run. Once you do it should reload after a few seconds and be working properly.

Comment: Looks like it was removed in recent versions, try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27112429/script-manager-not-showing-in-google-spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

The code has no problem.

```js
function dataValidation() {
  var array = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'];
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveCell();
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp
             .newDataValidation()
             .requireValueInList(array, true)
             .setAllowInvalid(false)
             .build();
  cell.setDataValidation(rule);
}
```

[image]

It looks like a permissions problem. Does the user that adds the code is the owner of the spreadsheet?

Comment: I am the owner of the spreadsheet, I should have the proper permissions to add such code. Might it be a Google Spreadsheet glitch?

Comment: Just for a test, create a new spreadsheet and try run the code.

Comment: Still the same issue: You do not have permission to call setDataValidation (line 9, file "Code")

Comment: I have the same problem, I'm able to run from the script editor but I get the permission problem in the spreadsheet.