# Script Manager Not Showing in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I've created a number of email scripts for our company's internal usage. Usually I create the script, save and then when I open the spreadsheet I can go to the Tools > Script Manager and run the script.

It is not showing up - only Script Editor and Script Gallery.

The script is not a "stand alone" script - I created it from the spreadsheet's Script Editor.

Is this something that has been disabled in the new Google spreadsheets? Or is there something else I need to code in the script to have it work?

Thank you.

Comment: they now have an option called macros under tools. it works wonderfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the new version of Sheets then the "Script Manager" is no longer a feature now as the New Sheets uses "Add-ons". You may find the resource on the link:

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2942256?hl=en

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out, it's been removed, but it's pretty easy to create a **custom menu** to call your method from:

Let's say you have a method `myCustomMethod` that you want to run from Google Sheets. Open the Script Editor and add the following code:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Run custom method', 'myCustomMethod')
      .addToUi();
}
```

Reload your sheet and you should see a new top-level menu next to Help, called "Custom Menu".

Comment: There is no script editor anymore in the tools menu

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember a 'Script Manager' setting, but I always run it from the script itself, so maybe I just wasn't looking. It has apparently been removed for some time so you may instead need to consider creating a [custom menu](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus) to run any function of the script.

**Edit**: I had a dig about an old version of sheets, and I could confirm this was in the old version:

[image]

[image]

But has been removed from the new version of sheets.

Comment: There was actually a menu item called script manager that used to list all the functions in the sheet project but this has been removed for quite a while... I just can't remember exactly when. :-)  Anyway, it's gone , and  I personally don't miss it since I found it less than useful.

Comment: This tickles the back of my mind a little. I think I have an inkling that I've seen that but mostly ignored it. Great to have confirmation it existed though.